# Spring Dependency: Order when loading beans according to the interface that they implement

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Is there any way in spring allowing the load of beans in a specific order according to the interface that they implement.

Example:
A , B and D implement an interface I1 
C and E implement an interface I2 .

I want that beans load A , B and D , than C and E .

Is there any way with spring ? 
Thanks .

Comment: Why does the order matter?

Comment: Look for Dagger or other Dependency Injection libraries

Comment: Spring will automatically create a graph of dependency and load beans in the order that they are needed (like if A depends on B and B depends on C, then it will load C first, then B, then A). If there is cyclic dependencies that cannot be resolved it will tell you. So you shouldn't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `@Order` to define the creation order for your beans.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html